# Problem rebooting macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, recovery, apfs

Need some help.
I made a partition of my hd (with high sierra), this new partition is an apfs where I installed another OS (Mojave).
I had some problems with restarting, so I could have accessed to the disk recovery and I thought about deleting the new partition.
I rebooted and it worked for a couple of times.
Now I am stuck with rebooting, it's like a loop, and can't access to the original high sierra.
I cannot even use the recovery mode or the internet recovery mode. The only mode I can access is the single mode user. I tried the recovery, it says the volume is ok but there are some problems with the apfs... I don't know what to do.
Is it possible to backup the files from single mode user and reinstall the os? Or boot the system in a way or another?
Hope what I wrote makes sense cuz I'm not too familiar with this world 
Thanks!

Comment: What model of Mac is this? (Only c. 2012 to 2018 models can use both those OSes.)  Probably best to wipe the disk and reinstall one OS.

Comment: If you can reach single user mode or recovery, then try to posting the output from the commands `diskutil list internal` and `sw_vers`.

Comment: Thanks! It's a macbook pro from 2013. Was working really good, till I did that...  I'll try with the command suggested.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but now it's working. After booting I checked the hd with disk utility. It says something about overallocation

Comment: I used the commands @DavidAnderson suggested. It shows the scheme and there are 4 apfs volumes: the volume that I'm using disk1s1. A volume called preboot disk1s2, one called Recovery volume and one VM.